# Mass apply copied range to multiple sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have a script that I use to apply mass changes to multiple spreadsheets

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "Update Sheets", functionName: "updateSheets"});
  ss.addMenu("Actions", menuEntries);
}


function ChangesAug1() {
 var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX').getSheetByName('ListOfSheetsToBeUpadated').getDataRange().getValues();    
  for (var row = 2; row < data.length; row++ ) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(data[row][0]).getSheetByName('Template');
```

And I have this other script I am using to copy and paste a range from one spreadsheet to another

```
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SourceID'); //replace with source ID
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('TemplateSheet'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
 var range = ss.getRange('A1:EJ5'); //assign the range you want to copy
 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('DestID'); //replace with destination ID
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('DestSheet'); //replace with dest
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,5,140).setValues(data); //you will need to define the size of the copied data see getRange()ination Sheet tab name
```

Any Idea on how I can combine the 2 scripts to mass apply a copied range from one sheet to a list of sheets ?

Thank you for responses :)

Comment: Have you tried something? What about searching on this site for smilar questions?

Answer (score 0):

You should just create a function that is used to copy the data wanted from one sheet to another and then call this function when accessing the sheets in the `for` loop you are using.

Therefore, you can use something similar to this:

```
function copyFromOneSheetToAnother(var sourceSheet,
   var destinationSheet) {
   var range = sourceSheet.getRange('A1:EJ5');
   var data = range.getValues();
   destinationSheet.getRange(ts.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 5, 140).setValues(data);
}
```

The above function is expecting two parameters: the `sourceSheet` and the `destinationSheet`. As for calling this function, you can just use this:

```
function ChangesAug1() {
   var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX').getSheetByName('ListOfSheetsToBeUpadated').getDataRange().getValues();
   for (var row = 2; row < data.length; row++) {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(data[row][0]).getSheetByName('Template');
      //get THE_DESTINATION_SHEET as well
      copyFromOneSheetToAnother(spreadsheet, THE_DESTINATION_SHEET);
   }
}
```

#### Reference

- [Sheet Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet);
- [Range Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).